# How do I calculate $s$ from $\mathbb P(X+Y>u\mid X<s)=q$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, truncated-normal-distribution

Suppose $X,Y$ are (not necessarily independently) normally distributed, how can one calculate the maximal limit $s$ that $X$ may reach such that the probability of the sum $X+Y$ overshooting a given limit $u$ is less than a certain $q$?

I wish to solve

$$\mathbb P(X+Y>u\mid X<s)=q$$

in $s$.

Comment: are X,Y multivariate normal? (I ask because there are multiple ways how X,Y can be normally distributed and not neccessarily independent)

Comment: yes, $X$ and $Y$ are multivariate normal.

Comment: Can't there be more than a single solution for $s$? If there is just a single solution you could try binary search.

Comment: @Haffi112 In most cases $P(Y>u-x|X=x)$ is an increasing or decreasing function of $x$ and there should be only a single solution. However, $P(Y>u-X|X=x)$ may be constant independent from x (when $\rho \sigma_y/\sigma_x =1$)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal distributed then $(X,X+Y)$ is also bivariate normal distributed. So, without loss of generality, one can consider the problem of solving
$$\mathbb P(Y>u\mid X<s)=q$$in $s$ when$$(X,Y)\sim\mathcal N_2\left(0_2,\left[\matrix{1 &\rho\\ \rho &1} \right]\right)$$since means and variances can be set to zero and one, respectively by location-scale changes in $u$ and $s$.

The above probability is then
$$\dfrac{\int_u^\infty\int_{-\infty}^s f(x,y)\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y}{\int_{-\infty}^s f(x)\,\text{d}x} = \dfrac{\int_u^\infty \varphi(y)\Phi(\{s-\rho y\}/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\,)\,\text{d}y}{\Phi(s)}$$
which in my opinion does not offer a closed-form solution.

Comment: (+1) FWIW, the integral has been expressed as an (infinite) sum of values of confluent hypergeometric functions: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.2942&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you point me to some resources about the calculation in your last equation? I can not quite follow these.

Comment: @Lukas it is the cumulative distribution of the bivariate normal distribution that occurs in that last equation ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function ). When you look for that you should find a solution (e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/).

Comment: $$\mathbb P(Y>u\mid X<s)=\frac{\mathbb P(Y>u,X<s)}{\mathbb P(X<s)}$$